# Arduino code giving error while compiling

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++

I am a beginner, and I'm trying to make code to control a servo using two ultrasonic sensors.
I've tried to make the code, but when I tried to compile it using my simulation app, it gives this error:

```
sketch.ino: In function 'void value2()':
sketch.ino:123:19: error: expected ')' before '!' token
 if((L < R)>=6 & L !> normal){
                   ^
sketch.ino: In function 'void value3()':
sketch.ino:131:19: error: expected ')' before '!' token
 if ((R< L)>=6 & R !> normal){
                   ^

Error during build: exit status 1
```

How do I go about fixing this?
I'm using the Wokwi simulator website, and here is the [link to the simulation](https://wokwi.com/projects/352784217989806081).

Here is where the problem is in my code:

```cpp
void value2() {
  /* I'm using L !> normal to make sure it doesn't run when L is greater than 750, and this is where the problem comes */
  if ((L < R) >= 6 & L !> normal) {
    servo.write(120);
    //goto 
    loop();
  }
}

void value3() {
  /* I'm using R !> normal to make sure it doesn't run when R is greater than 750, this is also where the problem comes */
  if ((R < L) >= 6 & R !> normal) {
    servo.write(60);
    //goto 
    loop();
  }
}
```

And here is my complete code:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
#define STEPS 100 // stepper steps
#define speed 30 // stepper speed
#define Lechopin 10 // ultrasonic sound sensor left 
#define Ltrigpin 11 // ultrasonic sound sensor left
#define Rechopin 12 // ultrasonic sound sensor right
#define Rtrigpin 13 // ultrasonic sound sensor right
long Lduration;
long Ldistance;
long Rduration;
long Rdistance;
int  L;
int  R;
int dt1 = 100; //delay
int dt2 = 1;   //delay
int dt3 = 2;   //delay
int dt4 = 10;  //delay
int serv = 9;  //servo pin
Servo servo;
Stepper stepper(STEPS, 5, 6, 7, 8);
/* Assuming distance of 4 feet measured by sensor is between 100 to 1000, let's set 750 as the normal distance between 
sensor and object in which will be anything in 4feet upward far 
away from sensor won't be detected by the code. you can edit it with real time measurement, I just assume this */
int normal=750;
int minn=250;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setSpeed(speed);
  servo.attach(serv);
  pinMode(Lechopin,INPUT);
  pinMode(Ltrigpin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Rechopin,INPUT);
  pinMode(Rtrigpin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  get_L_dist();
  L = get_L_dist();
  get_R_dist();
  R = get_R_dist();

  normalp();
  value1();
  value2();
  value3();

  //bailout;
}

//print sensors
/*
Serial.print("L is:");
Serial.println(L);
Serial.print("R is:");
Serial.println(R);
*/

/* read left sensor and calculate the distance */
long get_L_dist() {
  digitalWrite(Ltrigpin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(dt3);
  digitalWrite(Ltrigpin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(dt4);
  digitalWrite(Ltrigpin, LOW);
  Lduration=pulseIn(Lechopin, HIGH);
  Ldistance=Lduration / 58.2; 
  return Ldistance;
}

/* read right sensor and calculate the distance */
long get_R_dist() {
  digitalWrite(Rtrigpin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(dt3);
  digitalWrite(Rtrigpin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(dt4);
  digitalWrite(Rtrigpin, LOW);
  Rduration=pulseIn(Rechopin, HIGH);
  Rdistance=Rduration / 58.2; 
  return Rdistance;
}

//normal position of servo
void normalp() {
  if (L >= normal & R >= normal) {
    servo.write(90);
    //goto
    loop();
  }
}

void value1() {
  if ((L < minn) >= 2 & (R < minn) >= 2) {
    int ran = random(2);
    if (ran == 0) {
      servo.write(30);
      //goto
      loop();
    }
    if (ran == 1) {
      servo.write(150);
      //goto 
      loop();
    }
  }
}

void value2() {
  /* I'm using L !> normal to make sure it doesn't run when L is greater than 750, and this is where the problem comes */
  if ((L < R) >= 6 & L !> normal) {
    servo.write(120);
    //goto 
    loop();
  }
}

void value3() {
  /* I'm using R !> normal to make sure it doesn't run when R is greater than 750, this is also where the problem comes */
  if ((R < L) >= 6 & R !> normal) {
    servo.write(60);
    //goto 
    loop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `<=` instead of `!>`. The latter is not proper C++ syntax.

Also, `if (L < R) >= 6` probably doesn't do what you want. Did you mean `if (L - R) >= 6` maybe?

Comment: It really _can't_ do what they want. Because `L < R` in C++ will be either `true` or `false`, which will be considered 1 or 0 when when evaluated against `>= 6`. Taken as a whole `(L < R) >= 6` is always `false`. They also probably wanted `&&` rather than `&` although it may not exactly matter in this case. Ancient C didn't actually have `&&` and used `&` this way. Still probably not a good idea.

Comment: Please put these helpful answers as actual answers and not comments on the question. Thank you,

Comment: If you answer in comments, then this question will show up a year later with "no answers" because you answered in the comments. And that just annoys everyone.

Comment: @timemage See above.

Comment: @NickGammon, the bot bumps only answered questions (which have an answer without vote). We usually don't answer syntax error questions so let's see if this one gets closed.

Comment: @NickGammon it may be helpful. I'm not sure it constitutes answer. If I thought it did, it would _be_ an answer.

Comment: @NickGammon let me put it this way. If you take what I'd written and posted it as an "answer", I will vote it down. Because it is not an answer to the question. For thing it's describing code that compiles. It also does not having to do with that they _should_ do; it represents no part of a solution. It is hopefully dispelling some idea about what they think code is going to do. Anyway, you guys need to figure out what you actually want people to do. At a minimum, it would be helpful if you weren't calling people out for things they're not doing. Thank you.

Comment: @Juraj It's unlikely to get closed now. I'm not going to fault the answerer for doing what a mod was asking them to do. Particularly now that it's an accepted answer. It at least does attempt to address the compilation issue. I don't think addressing them is such a bad thing, particularly if there's anything arduino-related about either the question on answer, and is based on something that isn't just a typo. Either way, it would help to know what is supposed to be done. Or again, at a minimum, not to be getting crap for it.

Comment: @timemage *it would be helpful if you weren't calling people out for things they're not doing* - this is a Q&A site. People ask questions. You are supposed to answer them in the answer box. Comments under questions are for clarifying the question (eg. "what sort of Arduino do you have"). Not putting your answer into an answer box is a pretty big thing. I think I can occasionally "call it out". Personally I thought what you wrote was very good, and it deserved to be in an answer box. Then, people can vote it up or down. And you get credit for making the answer.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Juraj considers what I'd said an answer to the question. Either way, I don't care what you decide, but you and he and whoever else needs to figure out what is and isn't an answer and what is and isn't off topic. If everyone wants to define "answer" as _anything_ that is "good" (or "helpful" as I said) _irrespective_ of whether it actually answers the question that was asked, then I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<=` instead of `!>`; the latter is not proper C++ syntax.

Also, `if (L < R) >= 6` doesn't do what you may think: `(L < R)` evaluates to `true` or `false`, so the whole expression will always evaluate to `false`. Did you mean `if (L - R) >= 6` maybe?

Also, you use `&` as an "and" in your `if` statements, which should be `&&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ocrdu , I have modified it I use <= instead of !>, and I also changed ((L < minn)>= 2) to ((minn - L)>=2) and it is working on my simulation exactly as I need it to. Thanks to you all for helping me.